# Better way to extract a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string which is

`xyz.com/test/classified/electronics/home-audio-turntables/amplifiers/new/`.

I want to extract following value from above string i.e., `/classified/electronics/home-audio-turntables/amplifiers/`

I'm able to achieve this with the code below but is there a better way than this? Appreciate suggestions

```
window.location.href.split('test')[1].split('/new')[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

A regular expression can match what comes between.

```js
const str = 'xyz.com/test/classified/electronics/home-audio-turntables/amplifiers/new/';

const result = str.match(/test(\/.*?\/)new/)[1];
console.log(result);
```

Or with lookbehind

```js
const str = 'xyz.com/test/classified/electronics/home-audio-turntables/amplifiers/new/';

const result = str.match(/(?<=test)\/.*?\/(?=new)/)[0];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `window.location.pathname`

In case of testing:

```
window.location.pathname.replace(/^(\/test)?/, '')
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help. This gives me exactly what I want str.match(/test(\/.*?\/)new/)[1];